# How to define public constants in a custom AMD dojo widget

Tags: dojo

Up to dojo 1.6 I used to define public constants like this:

```
dojo.declare('x.y.Z', null, { ... });

x.y.Z.constant = 100;
```

This way they can be accessed from other code without instancing the class.

Since dojo 1.7 it is possible that my widget will be renamed or moved. So I should not use the absolute module ID inside my code.

What would be a good way to define such a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to attach it to a defined widget class, you can do something like this:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {
  var MyWidget = declare([], {
    //Define your widget as usual
  });

  MyWidget.someConstant = "42";

  return MyWidget;
});
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
require(["MyWidget"], function(MyWidget) {
  console.debug(MyWidget.someConstant); // Prints out "42"
});
```

Comment: My concern with that solution is that it isn't really a *constant*, it's a variable that resembles something "static" attached to the class. There's absolutely nothing preventing someone from doing `MyWidget.someConstant = "newvalue";`

Comment: The OP asked for a replacement of some Dojo 1.6 functionality; the property wasn't immutable in Dojo 1.6 either. Nonetheless, the pattern still applies. You could probably freeze() the widget, or at least freeze() an object that contains all the constants (though you could still replace the object). Or you could, you know, just not modify it.

Answer (score -1):

I would create an object inside the window object:

```
window.myConstants={};
window.myConstants.c1=100;
```

You can access the myConstants object from anywhere within your code, because it's a global object.

There are no real constants in javascript.

Comment: That would be a global constant. I'd like to have it coupled with my widget.